# Svg object doesn't scale properly

Tags: html, svg, xhtml

I am trying to making a svg object responsive so it scales nicely when viewing it on phone or tablet.

The [tutorial](http://demosthenes.info/blog/744/Make-SVG-Responsive) I used didn't help at all. Actually it made my text disappear entirely.

**Yeah, I'm using svg to mask text with gifs.** (Please understand that I'm just have started to learn general basics and don't assume that I know everything you're saying.)

Look at my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tappedout/yjLp4kbx/2/) for details.
If Jsfiddle not working check live [example](http://tappedout.net/users/Blind_Guardian/).

**HTML**

```
<h3>
<svg>
<pattern id="p-fire" viewbox="30 100 186 200" patternunits="userSpaceOnUse" width="216" height="200" x="-70" y="20">
<image xlink:href="http://tympanus.net/codrops-playground/assets/images/posts/23145/fire.gif" width="256" height="300">
</image></pattern>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%" dy=".35em" class="animatedtext">
            blind guardian
        </text>
</svg>
</h3>
```

**CSS**

```
body { background:black }

@font-face {
    font-family: "Toxia";
    src: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/yf4cv83buq5647x/tappedout/public/Toxia.ttf) format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Blood";
    src: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/yf4cv83buq5647x/tappedout/public/metal31.ttf) format("truetype"),
         url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/yf4cv83buq5647x/tappedout/public/metal31.woff) format("woff");
}

.animatedtext {
  fill: url(#p-fire);
  stroke: #8B0000;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
  font: 4em/1 Blood, bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your title responsive, you have to add a viewBox to the SVG.  For example

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 766 150">
```

Also note that SVG elements and attributes are case sensitive (although some browsers are forgiving) so it should be `viewBox`, not `viewbox`.

http://jsfiddle.net/yjLp4kbx/4/